# PHP SQLSRV export to Excel

Tags: php, sql, export-to-excel, sqlsrv

I am using PHP with SQLSRV in an attempt to export a table to Excel.  I used this method with MySQLi with no problem.

Regardless, here is the code I am using to export to Excel:

```
 <?php
   include("../include/database.php");
   global $ts; 
   $ts = date('mdY-His');
   session_start();

   $sql = "SELECT 
           [BOL_DATE]
           ,[BOOKING_NUM]
           ,[BOL_NUM]
           ,[VOYAGE]
           ....
           FROM DETAIL
           WHERE
           // bunch of other stuff not necessary to show";

   header("Content-Type: application/xls"); 
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=fulldetails-".$ts.".xls");  
   header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
   header("Expires: 0");
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

   $sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

   if($result = $dbc->sqlsrv_query($sql)) // <- error is here
  {
    while( $finfo = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
    {
      printf($finfo->name . $sep);
    }
  }

  print("\n");   

  while( $finfo = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
  {
    $schema_insert = "";
    for($j = 0; $j < sqlsrv_num_fields($result); $j++)
    {
      if(!isset($row[$j]))
        $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
      elseif ($row[$j] != "")
        $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
      else
        $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
    }
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";
  }
 ?>
```

The error I am getting upon firing this process, the Excel sheet shows this error:

```
 Fatal error:  Call to a member function sqlsrv_query() on a non-object in C:\server\htdocs\main\reports\reports.php
```

Which is pointing to the part above where I labeled "error is here".

On the line above where I pointed the error out, I even changed it to this:

```
 if($result = sqlsrv_query($dbc, $update))
```

But when the results are exported, the excel sheet is blank.

How can I edit my code to make this work?

Comment: Do you use PDO sqlsrv drivers or just sqlsrv drivers?